# Subclassing file in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 2, file was a proper class, so I wrote

```
class MyFile(file):  
  def floats_from_csv(self):  
    strs = self.read(1000000).split(',')  
    for i in strs:  
      yield float(i)

with MyFile("x.csv", "rt") as x:
  for i in x.floats_from_csv():
    ...
```

In python3 the numerous file replacements have no public constructors, so I can't subclass and get a `__init__` function. I have a hack using delegation, but it's ugly. What is the approved way to create subclasses of the builtin IO classes?

Comment: Why subclass at all? You could have defined that extra method as a freestanding function.

Comment: @larsmans: Why not subclass? One may want to add more/other functionality. And maybe even MixIn with multiple classes.

Comment: @cfi: subclassing causes tight coupling. A freestanding function causes avoids that and actually takes less code. One should subclass when existing behavior has to be altered, not when additional functionality has to be provided and it can be done entirely in terms of public methods.

Answer (score 4):

What I would do is replace your subtype by a general type that supports *any* file-like object (if it has a `read` method, it’s good enough) and just encapsulate it like this.

```
class MyCsvHandler():
    def __init__ (self, fileObj):
        self.file = fileObj

    def floatsFromCsv (self):
        strs = self.file.read(1000000).split(',')  
        for i in strs:  
            yield float(i)

with open('x.csv', 'r') as f:
    h = MyCsvHandler(f)
    for i in h.floatsFromCsv():
        # ...
```

That way, you could always replace your file object by a completely different thing, for example an IO object you get from a website, or some other stream from somewhere else.

Comment: There's no need for a class here.

Comment: @larsmans In this case, of course not, but I would believe that there might be a few more useful functions than this single one. I.e. this is just an example, but you could easily expand it to a more complex type that has multiple methods that are dependant on each other and share additional state. And then, you would definitely put that in a class.

Answer (score 0):

From the tiny fragment of code you have shown, I don't think subclassing is the best option.  However, if it's what you really want to do, check out [the IO module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html).